# Create byte stream from list of IEEE 754 single-precision (32-bit) floating point

Tags: java, algorithm

Is there a way to convert a list of IEEE single-precision (32-bit):

```
String result = getdata();
String[] floats = result.split(",");
List<String> floatList = Arrays.asList(floats);
```

The float data ultimately came from another module which generates `IEEE 754 single-precision (32-bit) floating-point number` from a byte stream.

Now I am trying to compile back the floating point values back to byte stream in Java.

Comment: How are you creating your byte stream?

Comment: Is it in binary or text?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The byte stream is generated from a streaming audio which is generated for the javascript interface by a SWF (Flash) module

Comment: @PeterLawrey The data is represented as comma-separated float value which is a String.

Comment: so you want to turn your float list into a comma separated string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the floating point values are stored as text within the String you can simply convert them number by number:

```
float[] floatValues = new float[floats.length]
for (int i=0; i< floats.length; i++) {
  floatValues[i] = Float.parseFloat(floats[i]);
}
```